# Run a application from batch file but hiding UI of that application

Tags: batch-file, user-interface

Is there any way to run the third party application, but user can't see the GUI of that application.

I am running the application and it is running, but what I want is to run it but user can't see the GUI of it.
Following code in batch file executes my application, here -w is a parameter which works as it is as one of the buttonPress event does form GUI-

```
@echo off
c:\xyz\abc.exe -w -pXXXXX
```

I want that if one runs the batch file, should not be able to see the GUI of that application so that pressButton event can't be created by the user.

Answer (score 0):

May this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php will help. I mean /MIN key for the command